# MySQL complicated join doesn't return what I would expect

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
SELECT a1.user_id
     , cwp1.value as status
     , COUNTa1.user_id) count
     , MIN(cwp1.display_order) lowest_status 
  FROM a1 
  JOIN ms1 
    ON ms1.model_id = a1.id 
  JOIN wp1 
    ON ms1.status_id = wp1.id
  JOIN cwp1 
    ON cwp1.workflow_parameter_id = wp1.id
 WHERE wp1.type = 12
   AND cwp1.company_id = 999
 GROUP 
    BY a.user_id 
 ORDER 
    BY lowest_status ASC
```

I then get `x` rows for distinct `user_id`, the issue is that a user can have more than one record in table `a1`.

So i said OK, i don't want random records, I want the one that has lowest `cwp1.display_order`. Unfortunately above query doesn't work, and still brings me random `a1` for a user.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You appear to be misusing the heinously confusing and nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. A good first step is to use `GROUP BY` correctly.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: it would be so much easier to help you, if you displayed the tables structures and explained the relation between them, and then explained what you wanted.

Comment: Better still, see the manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html